# XcodeでFFT(vDSP_fft_zrip)を使用するとFloat.infinityが出てしまう

Tags: swift, xcode

Mac/High Sierra 10.13.6/swift4.2/xcode 10.0

Xcodeのシミュレータから音を取得しFFTをかけると
Xcodeで結果にFloat.infinityが現れる
取得した音をファイル出力し、playground側で
読み込んでFFTをかけるとFloat.infinityが出ず、
結果が異なってしまうことに困っています。

音の取得部分は継続的に音を取得したいため
AQAudioQueueInputCallbackを利用し、
バッファに結果を格納しています。
[参考サイト](https://qiita.com/a_jike/items/68dd13879f9df5b2b7a2)
上記サイトと異なるところは上記サイトではInt8で音データをバッファから取得していますが、私はInt16で取り出しています。音のデータ形式が16ビットなので。
バッファにある程度溜まった段階で音波データを取得しFFTをかけるという処理をTimerでぐるぐる回しています。この時にFloat.infinityが出ることが確認できています。
一方で、この時同時に波形データをcsvで書き出しているのですが、この結果を使うとFloat.infinityが出ません。また、FFTで得られた結果はFloat.infinityが出ること以外はよく一致することも確認しています。
両者の違いとしてはTimerでくるくる回していることでしょうか。
ただ、毎回録音するためのオブジェクトはインスタンス化し直しているため、別のバッファを参照し、書き込んでいる間に読み出すと言ったような処理を行っていることも考えにくいです。
どうしてFloat.infinityが出てしまうのでしょうか。
FFTは下記のfftExecute(ntimes n:Int)で比較しております。ntimesが1でも2でも４でも結果は同様でした。
Float.infinityを0として扱い、両者のピーク構造を比較したところFloat.infinity以外の部分ではよく一致していました。

```
import Accelerate


class FFT {

    var delta:Float = 0
    var dataarray:[Float]?
    var datalength:Int?
    var rate:Float?
    var strength = [String:Float]()
    var frequency = [String:Float]()
    var strengthArray = [Float]()
    var frequencyArray = [Float]()


    init(_ vector:[Float],rate:Float){
        datalength = vector.count
        dataarray = vector
        self.rate = rate
    }

    init(_ vector:[Int8],rate:Float){
        datalength = vector.count
        dataarray = vector.compactMap({return Float($0)/Float(Int8.max)})
        self.rate = rate
    }

    init(_ vector:[Int16],rate:Float){
        datalength = vector.count
        dataarray = vector.compactMap({return Float($0)/Float(Int16.max)})
        self.rate = rate
    }

    func makeComplexVector(arr:inout [Float]) -> DSPSplitComplex {
        var empty:[Float] = Array<Float>(repeating:0.0,count:arr.count)
        let cvector=DSPSplitComplex(realp:&arr,imagp:&empty)
        return cvector
    }

    func applyWindowFunction(){
        // 窓関数
        //dataarrayに窓関数を適用してdataarrayに再格納
        var windowData = [Float](repeating:0,count: datalength!)
        var windowOutput = [Float](repeating:0,count: datalength!)
        vDSP_hann_window(&windowData, vDSP_Length(datalength!), Int32(0))
        vDSP_vmul(&dataarray!, 1, &windowData, 1, &windowOutput, 1, vDSP_Length(datalength!))
        dataarray = windowOutput
    }

    func createStrengthArray(){
        strengthArray = []
        for i in 0..<strength.count{
            strengthArray.append(strength[String(i)]!)
        }
    }
    func createFrequencyArray(){
        frequencyArray = []
        for i in 0..<frequency.count{
            frequencyArray.append(frequency[String(i)]!)
        }
    }

    func fftExecute(ntimes n:Int){
        let start = Date()//時間計測
        //窓関数の適用
        applyWindowFunction()

        if n > 1{addZeroArray(n)}

        delta = Float(dataarray!.count)/rate!
        let length = UInt(log2(Double(dataarray!.count*2)))
        let radix:FFTRadix = 2
        let set_up = vDSP_create_fftsetup(length, radix)
        var cvector = makeComplexVector(arr: &dataarray!)

        vDSP_fft_zrip(set_up!, &cvector, 1, length, 1)

        for i in 0..<datalength!{
            self.strength[String(i)] = sqrtf( cvector.realp[i]*cvector.realp[i] + cvector.imagp[i]*cvector.imagp[i] )
            self.frequency[String(i)] = Float(i)/delta
        }
        createStrengthArray()
        createFrequencyArray()
        //fft setupを解放する
        vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(set_up)
        let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)//時間計測終わり
        print("FFTの処理時間："+String(elapsed))//処理時間
    }
    //配列の長さををm倍してn分の1倍する
    func fftExecute(mtimes m:Int, ndivide n:Int){
        let start = Date()//時間計測
        //窓関数の適用
        applyWindowFunction()

        if m > 1 {addZeroArray(m)}

        delta = Float(dataarray!.count)/rate!

        if n > 1 {resizeArray(n)}

        let length = UInt(log2(Double(dataarray!.count*2)))
        let radix:FFTRadix = 2
        let set_up = vDSP_create_fftsetup(length, radix)
        var cvector = makeComplexVector(arr: &dataarray!)

        vDSP_fft_zrip(set_up!, &cvector, 1, length, 1)

        for i in 0..<datalength!{
            self.strength[String(i)] = sqrtf( cvector.realp[i]*cvector.realp[i] + cvector.imagp[i]*cvector.imagp[i] )
            self.frequency[String(i)] = Float(i)/delta
        }
        createStrengthArray()
        createFrequencyArray()
        //fft setupを解放する
        vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(set_up)
        let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)//時間計測終わり
        print("FFTの処理時間："+String(elapsed))//処理時間
    }
}
```

### 追加情報

@OOPerさんからいただいた情報をもとに直しました。
修正した内容は
・プロパティにreal(imag)FloatPointerを追加
・deinit{・・・}を追加
・makeComplexVectorの修正
です。

```
class FFT {

  var delta:Float = 0
  var dataarray:[Float]?
  var datalength:Int?
  var rate:Float?
  var strength = [String:Float]()
  var frequency = [String:Float]()
  var strengthArray = [Float]()
  var frequencyArray = [Float]()

  var realFloatPointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?
  var imagFloatPointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?


  init(_ vector:[Float],rate:Float){
      datalength = vector.count
      dataarray = vector
      self.rate = rate
  }

  init(_ vector:[Int8],rate:Float){
      datalength = vector.count
      dataarray = vector.compactMap({return Float($0)/Float(Int8.max)})
      self.rate = rate
  }

  init(_ vector:[Int16],rate:Float){
      datalength = vector.count
      dataarray = vector.compactMap({return Float($0)/Float(Int16.max)})
      self.rate = rate
  }

  deinit {
      realFloatPointer?.deallocate()
      imagFloatPointer?.deallocate()
  }

  func makeComplexVector(arr:inout [Float]) -> DSPSplitComplex {

      var empty:[Float] = Array<Float>(repeating:0.0,count:arr.count)
      realFloatPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: arr.count)
      realFloatPointer!.initialize(from: &arr, count: arr.count)
      imagFloatPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: arr.count)
      imagFloatPointer!.initialize(from: &empty, count: arr.count)
      let cvector=DSPSplitComplex(realp:realFloatPointer!,imagp:imagFloatPointer!)

      return cvector
  }

  func applyWindowFunction(){
      // 窓関数
      //dataarrayに窓関数を適用してdataarrayに再格納
      var windowData = [Float](repeating:0,count: datalength!)
      var windowOutput = [Float](repeating:0,count: datalength!)
      vDSP_hann_window(&windowData, vDSP_Length(datalength!), Int32(0))
      vDSP_vmul(&dataarray!, 1, &windowData, 1, &windowOutput, 1, vDSP_Length(datalength!))
      dataarray = windowOutput
  }

  func createStrengthArray(){
      strengthArray = []
      for i in 0..<strength.count{
          strengthArray.append(strength[String(i)]!)
      }
  }
  func createFrequencyArray(){
      frequencyArray = []
      for i in 0..<frequency.count{
          frequencyArray.append(frequency[String(i)]!)
      }
  }

  func fftExecute(ntimes n:Int){
      let start = Date()//時間計測
      //窓関数の適用
      applyWindowFunction()

      if n > 1{addZeroArray(n)}

      delta = Float(dataarray!.count)/rate!
      let length = UInt(log2(Double(dataarray!.count*2)))
      let radix:FFTRadix = 2
      let set_up = vDSP_create_fftsetup(length, radix)

      var cvector = makeComplexVector(arr: &dataarray!)

      vDSP_fft_zrip(set_up!, &cvector, 1, length, 1)

      for i in 0..<datalength!{
          self.strength[String(i)] = sqrtf( cvector.realp[i]*cvector.realp[i] + cvector.imagp[i]*cvector.imagp[i] )
          self.frequency[String(i)] = Float(i)/delta
          if self.strength[String(i)] == Float.infinity{
              self.strength[String(i)] = 0.0
          }
      }
      createStrengthArray()
      createFrequencyArray()
      //fft setupを解放する
      vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(set_up)
      let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)//時間計測終わり
      print("FFTの処理時間："+String(elapsed))//処理時間
  }
  //配列の長さををm倍してn分の1倍する
  func fftExecute(mtimes m:Int, ndivide n:Int){
      let start = Date()//時間計測
      //窓関数の適用
      applyWindowFunction()

      if m > 1 {addZeroArray(m)}

      delta = Float(dataarray!.count)/rate!

      if n > 1 {resizeArray(n)}

      let length = UInt(log2(Double(dataarray!.count*2)))
      let radix:FFTRadix = 2
      let set_up = vDSP_create_fftsetup(length, radix)
      var cvector = makeComplexVector(arr: &dataarray!)

      vDSP_fft_zrip(set_up!, &cvector, 1, length, 1)

      for i in 0..<datalength!{
          self.strength[String(i)] = sqrtf( cvector.realp[i]*cvector.realp[i] + cvector.imagp[i]*cvector.imagp[i] )
          self.frequency[String(i)] = Float(i)/delta
      }
      createStrengthArray()
      createFrequencyArray()
      //fft setupを解放する
      vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(set_up)
      let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)//時間計測終わり
      print("FFTの処理時間："+String(elapsed))//処理時間
  }



  //配列をn分の1のサイズにする
  func resizeArray(_ n:Int){
      var result = [Float]()
      for i in 0 ..< dataarray!.count{
          if i % n == 0 {
              result.append(dataarray![i])
          }
      }
      dataarray = result
  }
  //データに値が0の配列を足す n倍の長さになる
  func addZeroArray(_ n:Int) {
      let zeroArr = Array<Float>(repeating:0,count:dataarray!.count)
      var sum = dataarray!
      for _ in 0 ..< n-1 {
          sum += zeroArr
      }
      dataarray = sum
  }
  //ピーク値の辞書を返す
  func getPeakDict() -> [String:Float]{
      var peakDict = [String:Float]()
      for i in 0..<strength.count/2 {
          if i > 0 && strength[String(i-1)]! < strength[String(i)]! && strength[String(i)]! > strength[String(i+1)]! {
              peakDict[String(i)] = strength[String(i)]!
          }
      }
      return peakDict
  }

  func getSortedStrength() -> ([String],[Float]){
      let peakDict = getPeakDict()
      let sorted_strength = peakDict.sorted(){$0.value > $1.value}
      var rkey = [String]()
      var rvalue = [Float]()
      for (key,value) in sorted_strength {
          rkey.append(key)
          rvalue.append(value)
      }
      return  (rkey,rvalue)
  }

  //引数はmaxの強度に対してどの割合まで取得するかのスレッショルド
  func getPeakList(_ srd:Float,maxPeakNum mpn:Int) -> ([String],[Float],[Float]){
      var sortedStrength = [Float]()
      var sortedKey = [String]()

      var resultStrength = [Float]()
      var resultKey = [String]()
      var resultFrequency = [Float]()

      let tmp = getSortedStrength()
      sortedKey = tmp.0
      sortedStrength = tmp.1
      let maxStrength = sortedStrength[0]

      for i in 0..<mpn {
          if sortedStrength[i] > maxStrength*srd {
              resultStrength.append(sortedStrength[i])
              resultFrequency.append(frequency[sortedKey[i]]!)
              resultKey.append(sortedKey[i])
          }
      }
      return (resultKey,resultFrequency,resultStrength)
  }

  //nthは周波数が低い方から何番目のピークかを選択する引数
  //スタートは0
  func selectPeakFrequency(_ srd:Float,maxPeakNum mpn:Int,nth n:Int) -> Float{
      //結果にinfinityを含む場合は実施しない
      if !strengthArray.contains(Float.infinity){
          let peaklist = getPeakList(srd, maxPeakNum: mpn)
          let keylist = peaklist.0
          let freqlist = peaklist.1
          let sortedFreqList = freqlist.sorted() { $0 < $1 }
          var freq:Float = 0.0
          if n > freqlist.count{
              freq = sortedFreqList[freqlist.count]
          }else{
              freq = sortedFreqList[n]
          }
          var key = ""
          for i in 0..<freqlist.count{
              if freq == freqlist[i]{
                  key = keylist[i]
              }
          }
          let util = FFTUtil()
          freq = util.getPeakFreq(key, frequency, strength)
          return freq
      }
      else{
          return 0.0
      }
  }



  func getConponent(_ n:Int) -> ([String:[String:Float]],[Int]){
      /*
       並び替えて上位n番目まで値を取得する
       @note:return::[A:[B:C]] A:self.strength,self.frequency共通の通番のString変換 B:強さまたは周波数 C:値
       */
      var peakList = [String:Float]()
      for i in 0..<strength.count/2 {
          if i > 0 && strength[String(i-1)]! < strength[String(i)]! && strength[String(i)]! > strength[String(i+1)]! {
              peakList[String(i)] = strength[String(i)]!
          }
      }
      var keyarray = [Int]()
      let sorted_strength = peakList.sorted(){$0.value > $1.value}
      var component = [String:[String:Float]]()
      var i = 1
      for (key,value) in sorted_strength {
          keyarray.append(Int(key)!)
          component[key] = [String:Float]()
          component[key]!["strength"] = value
          component[key]!["frequency"] = frequency[key]!
          if i == n {
              break
          }
          i += 1
      }
      return (component,keyarray)
  }
```

}

Comment: とりあえず`makeComplexVector(arr:)`メソッド内での`DSPSplitComplex(realp:imagp:)`の使い方が間違っています。`realp`, `imagp`にはfftの処理中ずっと有効なアドレスを渡さないといけないのに、`&arr`, `&empty`という渡し方で作られるアドレスは次の行ではもう無効になるという一時的なものです。FFTは周波数領域に変換されているので、個々の時間領域でのサンプルにとんでもない変な変換をしたとしてもほとんど同じ結果が出たりします。同じ傾向のデータが出ると言うのはあまり重要な情報にはなりません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。DSPSplitComplex(realp:imagp:)はUnsafeMutablePointerを入れれば良いと理解しました。公式ドキュメントにあるように、var bytes: [UInt8] = [39, 77, 111, 111, 102, 33, 39, 0]
let uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 8)
uint8Pointer.initialize(from: &bytes, count: 8)という風にしてこれのFloat型を作って上記コードのuint8Pointerを入れれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: ほぼ正しく理解してもらっているように思います。実数部と虚数部があるから`realPointer`と`imagPointer`とかですね。`allocate`されたポインタを渡せば、`deallocate`を呼ぶまで(どこかで呼んでやらないといけません)無効になったりしないので大丈夫と言うことになります。ただし、データの取得部を見ていないので、それを解消したところで全部解決するかどうかまではわかりません。念のため。

Comment: ありがとうございます。安心いたしました。データの取得に関してはAudioQueueStartクラスで録音を開始し、mAudioDataから定義したバッファにコピー。まだOOPerさんから提示いただいたソースに改修できていないのでvar buffer: UnsafeMutableRawPointerとなっています。16bitPerChannelなので下のdata.lengthの1/2倍してバッファポインタで取得しています。
let data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: audioService.buffer, length: num)
let datalength = data.length/2
let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self), count: datalength)

Comment: データの取得については、回答者に義理立てして、動いているものを無理に書き換える必要はないと思います。性能改善の必要性を感じられたときにでも、なんかでも良いでしょう。ただコードというのは前後関係も含めて初めて正誤が判断できるものなので、断片だけでは何とも言えません。修正後のコードで引き続き(あるいは別の)不具合が見られるなら必要に応じて提示していただければ良いと思います。

Comment: @OOperさん、アドバイスいただき、事象が解消致しました。Playgroundとxcodeプロジェクトでの挙動の違いがなんとも難しいです。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。時間をとって自己回答をお願いします。Playgroundについては、慣れてもらって自分なりの使い分けをしてもらわないと仕方ないですね。